# Table alignment and text overflow

Tags: tables

I have problems with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{0.2\linewidth} 
>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}m{0.55\linewidth} >{\centering \arraybackslash}     
m{0.2\linewidth}}
\toprule
\centering Semester & \centering Course &  \centering Grade \tabularnewline \midrule
\multirow{5}{\linewidth}{\textsc{Semester 9\linebreak  SomeUniversity, Someplace \linebreak  
30 ECTS}} & blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla& K
\tabularnewline
    & blablabla & L
\tabularnewline
    & Specialization Course: blablablablablablablablablablablabla & L               
\linebreak -    randomcourse1 \linebreak - randomcourse2 & M
\tabularnewline & randomcourse3 & N
\tabularnewline & randomcourse4 & O
\tabularnewline
\midrule dasd&dsads&dasdszzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\tabularnewline dad&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz&das
\tabularnewline zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline dad&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline dad&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this 
[image]
There are 3 problems:
1) the text overflows, even though I specified the \linewidth 
2) The top-right cell is not aligned vertically
3) The whole table is not centered

I am new to LaTeX, but I searched a lot and spent a crazy amount of time on this without improvement. Do you have ideas please ?

Comment: latex can not hyphenate `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` so it has no way to keep this in the specified size, if your real text is natural language text with word spaces you may want `\raggedright` but if your real text is long codes such as this you will need to specify custom line breaking (there are answers on site for breaking strings)

Comment: I solved the 3rd problem. If it has to overflow, I guess I could use some `\linebreak` I guess, even if it doesn't seem like an optimal solution.
However, I would really like to align the 'semester 9' etc vertically, but am unable to find how ...

Comment: Not quite sure what alignment you want but I suspect you want `p` rather than `m`

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself clearly enough, English isn't my first language. 
Anyway, I would like to have the "semester... ECTS" to be exactly vertically centered, i.e. in the middle compared to the 2 horizontal lines. Therefore, p-alignment i.e. top alignment would not solve the problem :S

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\centering
\begin{tabular}{
>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}m{0.25\linewidth}
>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}m{0.55\linewidth}
c
c}
\toprule
\centering Semester & \centering Course &  \centering Grade \tabularnewline \midrule

\smash{\raisebox{-3\normalbaselineskip}{\scshape
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Semester 9\\
SomeUniversity,\\
 Someplace\\  
30 ECTS
\end{tabular}}} &
 blablablablablablablablablablablab\newline
lablablablablablablablablabla& K
\tabularnewline
    & blablabla & L
\tabularnewline
    & Specialization Course: blablablablablablablablablablablabla & L               

% ??\linebreak -    randomcourse1 \linebreak - randomcourse2 & M
\tabularnewline & randomcourse3 & N
\tabularnewline & randomcourse4 & O
\tabularnewline
\midrule 
dasd&dsads&dasdsz
%??zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\newline zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\tabularnewline 
dad&zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\newline zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz&das
\tabularnewline 
zzzzz\newline zzzzzzzz\newline zzzzzzzzzzzzzz\newline
zzzzzzzzzzzzz\newline
zzzzzzzzzzzzz&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline dad&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline dad&dsaasd&das
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @alexanzi note I deleted (comented out)  the excessively long entries in the final _Grade_ column as I assumed your real case wouldn't have them (or the table needs a different layout)